# How to insert ' into postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use `python` package `psycopg2` to update database.

```
cur.execute("UPDATE scholars SET name='{}' WHERE id={} and name is null".format(author, scholar_id))
```

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "Neill"
LINE 1: UPDATE scholars SET name='O'Neill, Kevin' WHERE id=12403 and...`

data should be:`O'Neill, Kevin`

Comment: Please read how to pass arguments to SQL queries without having the risk of SQL injection attacks: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

Comment: Try swapping to placeholders. `cur.execute("UPDATE scholars SET name=%s WHERE id=%s and name is null", (author, scholar_id))`. Bonus, you're not so exposed to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Psycopg's parameter passing functionality](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters):

```
cur.execute ("""
    UPDATE scholars 
    SET name = %s 
    WHERE id = %s and name is null
    """,
    (author, scholar_id)
)
```

[Triple quotes make it clearer](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)